# How can I make lime plaster more resistant to vibration?

Tags: plaster

I have a tiny house that I've just put some drywall up in. I am partial to the look and feel of Venetian/lime plaster, but since the house will move periodically I want to be sure it won't crack too much.

Here's a person who put lime plaster into their tiny house: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=maMG1T8_u4I

He does comment on how it cracks when he drives it at about 5 minutes.

Is there a natural additive that will help prevent cracks/make the plaster somewhat more flexible?

I'm open to experimenting too :)

Comment: how are you measuring natural?

Comment: They used to put horse hair in plaster.

Comment: @Jasen Also flexible but generally something non-toxic and compostable.

Comment: @SteveWellens That's pretty cool! Would any kind of hair work for this?

Comment: I don't know.   Probably not hair from blondes, they have really fine hair.  Try google.

Comment: I was going to suggest glass fibre. which is basically engineered dirt. using some sort of engineered wood behind the plaster would probably help. eg: plywood

Comment: Well, at least you used drywall instead of carpet.... Paint the whole thing with crack isolation membrane before you faux plaster over it? But that probably doesn't meet fire code either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think panels. The reason wood works so well is that each board can move 1/16” or so and the wood doesn’t crack or come apart.

Install gypsum board with plaster in panels that are allowed to move a bit and they won’t crack and fall apart either. You’ll need to experiment to determine the maximum size panel that will work in your case.

In addition, stiffen the under carriage so the entire building will not flex and twist during moving.

I’d use the “flexible” gypsum board panels (with your lime plaster over.) See USG 1/4” panel. Here’s an article about it:

https://www.usg.com/content/dam/USG_Marketing_Communications/united_states/product_promotional_materials/finished_assets/sheetrock-gypsum-panels-quarter-inch-flexible-submittal-WB2128.pdf

Comment: Im imagining that you put the plaster over the drywall in rectangular sections that resemble bricks. Is this correct? If so, how would you acheive it? couldn't find it on google, but maybe I don't know what to google.

Comment: @JoeB Yes, directly over the “flexible” gypsum board. I’d recommend panels that are square-ish, but they don’t need to look like bricks. I’m thinking plaster looking, but in sections up to 8’ x 8’ or so.

Comment: would you recommend using mesh lathe for this application?

Comment: @JoeB Not sure if mesh isn’t better or not. I know Venetian plaster is more flexible than gypsum plaster or thin set plaster. (Thinset plaster has a very hard finish on the surface and you probably don’t want it.) I’d contact a plaster association for assistance, then experiment. Here’s one: https://mnlath-plaster.com/